# nodejs copy cookies for internal app request

Tags: node.js, session, express

I am using Express 3.x and connect-mongo and the request module

My App has some middleware that ensures the external request has an access_token. 
The access_token is checked and a some data is stored in the session.
I then want to make an internal call to a url within the application, but the internal call gets issued a new session (as its a separate request from the users browser request). 
What I want to do is somehow copy the Express signed cookies across into the internal request() so that the middleware performs actions based on the original external session id.
I have tried passing a cookie jar into the request object but it doesnt seem to support signed cookies very well. Any ideas how I can do this?

```
/* Middleware to check access tokens */
app.all("/*", requireAuth, function(req, res, next) {
  next(); 
});

function requireAuth(req,res,next) {

if ( req.query.access_token && !req.session ) {

   // Check the access token and popualte stuff in the session
   req.session.somedata = 'test';

   // Then call a url internall to do something

   // My issue is that this INTERNAL request below gets a new session Id
   // so it itself returns Not Authorised as its hits the same code

   request({
       url: 'someurlinside-this-node-app',
       method: "GET"
   }, function _callback(err, serviceres, body) {
       next();
   });

 }else{
     res.send('Not Authorised');
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are just another header so if you want to pass it along you should be able to do this:

```
var cookies = req.header('Set-Cookie');

request({
       url: 'someurlinside-this-node-app',
       method: "GET",
       headers: { 'Set-Cookie' : cookies}
   }
```